Finding a .mbtiles to bitmap (BMP) converter
I was trying to create this project : https://github.com/middelbh/GPSnavigator/tree/master
and it needs .bmp files of a map to read it by arduino. So which is the best converter to convert .mbtiles to 8 bit .bmp file? or .mbtiles to GeoTIFF and then converting to 8-bit BMP format?

Gdal_translate can do that.

@user30184 then how could i do it using Gdal translate? Or can I find a tutorial for it?

I would read first the documentation from https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html. The BMP driver page is probably useful as well. I am sure that you can find easily gdal_translate usage examples. If I remember right the max size of a BMP image is 4 GB so you may need to convert only a part of your .mbtiles file. See the options of gdal_translate.
